# Find Element by partial Xpath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to define specific elements, the only way in which they differ is how the 'div' changes like below (the 1st element I want has div[1], second div[2] etc.

```
//*[@id="search-content-container"]/div/bls-search/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/bls-connection/div/div[2]/div**[1]**/bls-connection-step/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1] 

//*[@id="search-content-container"]/div/bls-search/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/bls-connection/div/div[2]/div**[2]**/bls-connection-step/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1] 

//*[@id="search-content-container"]/div/bls-search/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/bls-connection/div/div[2]/div**[3]**/bls-connection-step/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]
```

How do I specify this in Selenium to allow me to find all 'i'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Can you find these div[n] elements as a list, then do element.findElement on each in a loop?

Comment: Can you share the html for the above locators ?

Comment: These locators are going to be really brittle... meaning they will break at the smallest change in HTML because they contain so many nested levels of elements. It would be better if you shared some of the relevant HTML or better yet a link to the page with some description of what you are trying to locate.

Comment: @Rory Spies, You are using absolute XPath detection, Which is never good. You should Relative XPath. In order to define Relative XPath for your code, You need to share HTML block of target element.